# Can any vector not in a linear space be separated from it?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

For context, I was exploring a bit more [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329012/about-convex-set-a-satisfying-a-bigcap-f-in-e-ast-f-1fa) I asked before.

Suppose that $E$ is a vector space such that its algebraic dual $E^\ast$ can separate point, i.e. for all $x\in E\setminus\{0\}$, there is $f\in E^\ast$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$.

I am wondering if the following can be proved or disproved :

> If $S$ is a linear subspace of $E$, and $x\notin S$, then there is $f\in E^\ast$ such that $f(x)\notin f(S)$

I am not sure exactly on how to address this, but first it is obvious that such a $f$ will be such that $f(S)=\{ 0\}$, otherwise $f(S)=\mathbb R$. Therefore we are looking for $f\in E^\ast$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$ and $f(S)=\{0\}$. Otherwise, I thought about assuming the statement is wrong and then try to create a point $y\in S$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $f\in E^\ast$ which would prove that $x=y\in S$, maybe some sort of projection of $x$ on $S$ but I don't know how to do that from just $E^\ast$ and no norm. Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that the only possibility for the algebraic dual to separate points is that $E$ has dimension 1: $\dim_{\mathbb{K}}E = 1$. Since $f:E\to \mathbb{K}$ implies that f cannot be injective unless $E$ and $\mathbb{K}$ has the same dimension. In this case, the only non-trivial linear subspace is $S = E$ and, therefore, we have $f(S) = \mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Maybe I miss something but since you don't have to care about continuity/topology, why can't you take $f\colon E=\Bbb K x \oplus W, tx+v \mapsto t$?

Comment: @Davius Then I must have formulated it wrong, for instance in $E=\mathbb R^2$, if $x\neq 0$ then at least one of $x\to x_1$ or $x\to x_2$ will be a function $f$ in $E^\ast$ such that $f(x)\neq f(0)=0$. Does that seem correct to you ?

Comment: @GhostAmarth I have seen in the book Topological Vector spaces by Schaefer that (independent of topology) if $S$ is a subspace of $E$ then there is a subspace $W$ of $E$ such that $E=S\oplus W$. I haven't compltely understood the example provided and it may be that because $\mathbb K x$ is a 1 dimension subspace that we can find such a $W$, however that is not something I know, that would indeed make my problem very simple. Any reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: @P.Quinton Sadly I don‘t have a reference at hand right now, but I will try to dig somenthing up. I believe we could prove the existence of a $W$ with $E=\Bbb K x\oplus W$ by using Zorns lemma on the set $\mathcal M = \{V\subseteq E : V \text{ is subspace and } V\cap \Bbb Kx =\emptyset\}$.

Comment: If you assume Zorn's lemma, then the result is essentially obvious, because every vector space has a basis and every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following result needs Zorn's lemma ($\Leftrightarrow$ axiom of choice)

Let $V\subseteq E$ be a subspace and $\mathcal M = \{W\subseteq E : W \text{ is subspace and } W\cap V = \{0\}\}$. We  give $M$ a partial order via $V_1 \leq V_2 :\Leftrightarrow V_1 \subseteq V_2$.
Let $\Gamma \subseteq \mathcal M$ be a chain (a totally ordered subset). We show that $\Gamma$ has an upper bound. Note that $\{0\}\in \mathcal M \neq \emptyset$.

Case $\Gamma = \emptyset$: Any element $x\in\mathcal M$ is an upper bound for $\Gamma$.

Case $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$: Define
\begin{align*}
R = \bigcup_{S\in\Gamma} S
\end{align*}
Now $R\cap V = \{0\}$ and $R$ is a subspace of $E$, as one verifies as follows: Let $x_1, x_2\in R$. Then $\exists S_1, S_2 \in \Gamma$ with $x_1\in S_1, x_2\in S_2$. Since $\Gamma$ is totally ordered, we may assume (by possibly interchanging $x_1$ and $x_2$) that $S_1 \leq S_2$, so $x_1,x_2 \in S_2$. Thus for $s,t\in\Bbb K$ we have $sx_1+tx_2 \in S_2 \subseteq R$. Thus $R\in\mathcal M$ and $R$ is an upper bound for $\Gamma$, since $S\subseteq R$ for every $S\in \Gamma$.

Hence every chain in $\mathcal M$ has an upper bound in $\mathcal M$ and we imploy Zorn's lemma to get a maximal element $W\in\mathcal M$. By definition $W\cap V = \{0\}$.

It remains to show $V+W = E$. Suppose $x_0 \in E\setminus (V+W)$.
We show $(W+\Bbb K x_0) \cap V = \{0\}$. If $w+tx_0 \in (W+\Bbb K x_0)\cap V$, then $tx_0 \in -w+V \subseteq W+V$, thus $t=0$ (as $x_0\neq 0$). So $w=w+tx_0 \in W\cap V =\{0\}$, so $w=0$.

Thus $(W+\Bbb K x_0) \cap V = \{0\}$ and $W\subsetneq W+\Bbb K x_0$, so $W$ would not be maximal in $\mathcal M$ $\unicode{x21af}$.

Thus $E=V\oplus W$.

---

To get your desired result we take $V=\Bbb K x$. Now $E=\Bbb K x \oplus W$ for some $W\subseteq E$. Let
$$
\lambda\colon E=\Bbb K x \oplus W \mapsto \Bbb K,\ tx+w \mapsto t.
$$
Then $\lambda\in E^*$and $\lambda(x) = 1 \not\ni \{0\} = \lambda(W) \supseteq \lambda(S)$.

Comment: Very nice proof. For the last part, I'm wondering about the following example in $E=\mathbb R^2$, let $x=[1,1]^T$ and $S=\{ [x,0]^T:x\in\mathbb R \}$, then your $\lambda$ would be something like $[x,y]^T\to \frac{x+y}{2}$ and therefore $\lambda(S)=\mathbb R$. If that is correct then we need a bit of tweaking, however I think using a direct sum could be the key (so please don't remove the answer).

Comment: Thinking about it again, I think we can basically do the same but decomposing $E=S\oplus W$, taking any element $a\in W$ (which exists because $x$ is not in $S$), then write $E=\mathbb Ka\oplus W'$ and setting $\lambda :\mathbb K a \oplus W', ta+w\to t$, or something of that flavor. We probably need an extra assumption on $a$ so that $\lambda(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your example. Since $x\notin S$ we know $\Bbb K x \cap S = \{0\}$. Otherwise $tx \in S \Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{t}tx \in S$ for $t\neq 0$ (and we also know $x\neq 0$ as $0\in S$). Thus $S$ is contained in $\mathcal M$ and thus $S\subseteq W$ (since $W$ is maximal). Now my $\lambda$, by definition, maps $\lambda(W) = \lambda(0x+W) = \{0\}$ and since $S\subseteq W$ also $\lambda(S)=\{0\}$. On the other hand $\lambda(x) = \lambda(1x + 0) = 1$.

Comment: Regarding your example $x=(1,1), S=\Bbb R \times \{0\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$ we could use $W=S=\Bbb R (1,0)$. My $\lambda$ would then look like $t(1,1)+s(1,0) \mapsto t$, so $\lambda(S)=\{0\}$ and $\lambda(x) = 1$.

Comment: Sorry about that I got a bit confused. Actually I still am, in your last comment if we look at $\mathcal W$, it contains all lines that are not $x=y$ but to me, the only upper bound on them that is linear is $\mathbb R^2$. This is surprising to me, especially since I can't find anything wrong in your proof.

Comment: Reading this I think maybe your confusion is rooted in the definition of a "maximal element". Note that on $\mathcal M$ we only have a partial order. this means there are elements we can't compare to each other (for example neither $\Bbb R(1,1) \leq \Bbb R(1,2)$ nor $\Bbb  R(1,2) \leq \Bbb R(1,1)$). An element $m\in\mathcal M$ ($\mathcal M$ can be any partially ordered set) ist called maximal, if $m\leq s \Rightarrow s\leq m$ for any $s\in\mathcal M$. This means you don't have to be able to compare any element with $m$, but when you can, $m$ must be larger (or equal)

Comment: In your case: $\Bbb R(1,0)$ is maximal. Whenever $S\in\mathcal M$ satisfies $\Bbb R(1,0) \leq S$ (so $\Bbb R(1,0) \subseteq S$) we must have $S\subseteq \Bbb R(1,0)$. This is simply due to the fact that any $S\in\mathcal M$ with $\Bbb R(1,0)\subseteq S$ ist at least 1-dimensional. But it can't be larger, because any 2-dimensional subspace would be the whole $\Bbb R^2$ and thus contain $(1,1)$, which contradicts our construction of $\mathcal M$.